# How would I use templates with QVector?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Currently, I have this:

```
void ClassA::aFunction(QVector<ClassB *> items) {
    //stuff
}
```

I would like to turn the parameter for ClassA::aFunction into a QVector with templates:

```
template <class T *> class QVector;
void ClassA::aFunction(QVector<T *> items) {
    //stuff
}
```

This is giving me syntax errors, so what is the correct way to do this?

**Edit:**

I have this now:

*classA.h:*

```
template <class T>
class ClassA {
public:
    void myFunction(ClassB *);
}
```

*classA.cpp:*

```
template <class T>
void ClassA<T>::myFunction(ClassB * b) {
    QVector<T *> var = b->myBFunction();
}
```

*classB.h:*

```
template <class T>
class ClassB {
public:
    void myBFunction();
private:
    QVector<T *> myVar;
}
```

*classB.cpp:*

```
template <class T>
QVector<T *> ClassB<T>::myBFunction() {
    return this->myVar;
}
```

I have a syntax error "member declaration not found" with ClassA::myFunction. I also have an error "method 'myBFunction' could not be resolved" in ClassA::myFunction. How do I fix these two errors?

**Edit2**
Figured this out:

*classA.h:*

```
class ClassA {
public:
    template <class T> void myFunction(ClassB *);
}
```

*classA.cpp:*

```
template <class T>
void ClassA::myFunction(ClassB * b) {
    QVector<T *> var = b->myBFunction<T>();
}
```

*classB.h:*

```
class ClassB {
public:
    template <class T> void myBFunction();
private:
    template <class T> QVector<T *> myVar;
}
```

*classB.cpp:*

```
template <class T>
QVector<T *> ClassB::myBFunction() {
    return this->myVar;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost right:

```
template <class T> void ClassA::aFunction(QVector<T *> items)
{
    //stuff
}
```

You'll have to declare that in the same way inside the class definition:

```
class ClassA
{
  template <class T> void aFunction(QVector<T*>);
  // ...
};
```

By the way, why are you passing a `QVector` by value?

Comment: Thanks it works! Should I be passing the QVector by reference?

Comment: @DiZou: Yes, in all likelihood you should. Const-reference if you don't modify it.

Comment: Note that Qt containers have copy-on-write semantics, so passing them by reference to avoid unnecessary copying isn't strictly necessary: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq19-containers.html

Comment: @KerrekSB: I have a couple new errors, could you help with those? I edited the original post. Thanks!